# FreeBSD install python31 over python27

Tags: python

Hi I had installed python27 and after python31, I tried to deinstall python27 but it seems that this version is standing on host. How can I set python31 to become main python ?

[image: Install process.]

Comment: You should know that text is preferable to a screenshot.

Comment: Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. Also use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line to `/etc/make.conf` file:

```
DEFAULT_VERSIONS=python=3.4
```

And install `lang/python` port. This will make Python 3.4 your default python version. I recommend you reinstall all ports that depend on python and finally remove python2.7:

```
pkg delete python27
```

Comment: It says that python27 is not installed but when I use python-v i get python27

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*` says? It seems your previous python installation was not cleanly removed.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9oaipn

Comment: How about `pkg info | grep ^python` ?

Comment: pkg info is not installed and grep ^python in 2min doesn't showed anything.Btw how I make in console the "|" symbol?

Comment: seems like you are running an older version of FreeBSD which does not come with `pkg`. Try `pkg_info` command. "|" symbol is usually shift+\.

Comment: Another options is to installed python27 again and uninstall it cleanly. It would solve the problem. `cd /usr/ports/lang/python27 && make install && make deinstall`

Comment: I run the freebsd 9.2 on virtual box and 2nd network in my normal network  and I always get No adressrecord,seems that vm box takes only first network

Comment: maybe if I delete /usr/ports/lang/python27?

Comment: I rename the folder and still 2.7.5 is the version